# restore mongodb database .bson and .json files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

In this folder called `my_backup` I have a **mongodb database dump** with all my **models/collections** for example:

```
admins.bson
admins.metadata.json
categories.bson
categories.metadata.json
pages.bson
pages.metadata.json
.
.
.
```

I have a database called `ubuntu_development` on mongodb. I am working with `rails 3 + mongoid`

**How can I import/restore all models/collections from the folder `my_backup` to my database `ubuntu_development`**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! This was a nightmare for me...

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Execute this command from the console (in this case):

```
mongorestore my_backup --db ubuntu_development
```

1. `mongodbrestore` is followed by `my_backup`, which is the folder name where the previous dump of the database is saved.
2. `--db ubuntu_development` specifies the database name where we want to restore the data.

Comment: Also, if you don't already have the target database created, simply put the restore files in a folder with the name of the database you want, and do `mongorestore <foldername>`. This will create the database `foldername` and put all the date in there :)

Answer (score 6):

To import .bson files

```
mongorestore -d db_name -c collection_name path/file.bson
```

Incase only for a single collection.Try this:

```
mongorestore --drop -d db_name -c collection_name path/file.bson
```

To import .json files

```
mongoimport --db db_name --collection collection_name --file name.json
```